# Meaning of Compile-Time?

Tags: .net, vb.net

My Question: What exactly does “compile-time” mean? I present my understanding below and where I am getting confused.

Compilation is the process that generates a single executable .exe file from the .vb file. There are several ways to do this, for example by using the VBC.EXE command from the developer command window or MSDOS. The way I understand “compile-time” is that it is time when such a command gets executed and the exe file is generated. The following are the what I find confusing:

1. When I write Dim i = 5, the compiler infers or “knows” that the variable “i” is an integer.
2. If I want to print an integer or a string using the Writeline method of the console class then the compiler automatically determines which overloaded version it should call. So in this case also the compiler “knows” – this is also known as compile-time polymorphism.

My confusion: Since in both the above cases the compiler infers or knows the type of variable or the version of the overloaded method to call just after we have finished typing the sentence, is this also called compile-time? We have not given any sort of compilation command here.

3. Another confusion on the definition of compile-time refers to the case when we explicitly define overloaded methods. In the case of the writeline method, we know from the pop-up given by intellisense that immediately after we have finished typing the sentence the version with the correct signature is called. Now, when we define overloaded methods does the compiler know which version to call when we call the function (depending on signature) somewhere in the program right after we have finished typing the code? Or does the compiler know this after the exe file has been generated? This is a case of compile-time polymorphism. But then which time or which step is the “compile-time”?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We have not given any sort of compilation command here.

No, but most modern IDEs can do similar "static analysis" that compilers do to determine types, etc. Some even do a very lightweight "compile" to determine what overloads are appropriate, etc.

Also note that IDEs and the actual compiler *may not always agree*. IDE analysis is designed to be *very* fast, so the analysis done by the IDE may be less robust and less accurate than a static compiler.

So in a sense these are all "compile-time" in that the only information that is available is what is present in the code. This is opposed to "run-time" where other factors such as user input, environment, and state can change the flow and interpretation of the program in ways that the compiler could not account for.